# Sum column values into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to find a way to sum these columns into the lower row. I'm using VBA for an exercise but I don't seem to get it without relying on referencing to each cell.

The result should be an array in which each item is the sum of the values of the table's column and then print the array into the range shown in the picture.

What happens if the number of rows in the column changes?

[image: Table]

This is the code I have tried:

```
Sub cambios_combobox()
Dim librito As Worksheet
Dim celda As Range

Set librito = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla Paquetes")
Set celda = Range("A40")
'Range("Table1[[#All],[Column1]]").Select
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "Deco"
            Range("eq_asis").Value = Application.Sum(librito.Range("Tabla2[Asistente fotografía]"))
            Range("eq_asis").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
...
```

It goes like that, referencing every single cell in that row, summing values up. I figure there must be another way to do that without so much waste.

Comment: What VBA code have you tried? Please show an attempt.

Comment: Added it to the post :)

Comment: Is that a normal table or a pivot table?? Are you using arrays because it is a good strategy or because it's a learning exercise??

Comment: It's a normal table. I believe arrays are a better strategy than going with loop of some sort. Also I am learning how to code VBA in the process.

Comment: So is your code intended to update those totals whenever the table is filtered? Do you only want to sum currently visible rows? Changes in the number of table rows shouldn't affect anything if you are referencing it by column name as you show.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just set ShowTotals to True for object Table1?

Comment: Because I want substract another quantity from a different table which changes dynamically as I change values in the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will put the totals formulas in that row. It first shows the totals row and then applies a formula in it that sums all visible cells in the current column starting at row 2 (R2C) and ending with the cell right above the sum (R[-1]C). Excel might convert this R1C1 notation to A1 notation when it transfers the formula to the cells. Obviously change `Sheet2!R1C2` to whatever other cell you are subtracting from the sum.

```
Public Sub showTotalsMinusOtherCell()
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set lst = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    lst.ShowTotals = True
    lst.TotalsRowRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=Subtotal(109,R2C:R[-1]C)-Sheet2!R1C1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Mark, I do not understand the last line of code:
    lst.TotalsRowRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=Subtotal(109,R2C:R[-1]C)-Sheet2!R1C1"
Why is the Subtotal() range (109,R2C:R[-1]C)?

Comment: I am applying a formula to the cells in the totals row. The first parameter (109) is just a code to EXCEL which basically means 100 (visible cells) + 9 (SUM function). The second parameter represents the range to perform said SUM function on. I have chosen R1C1 notation so I don't have to determine the column letter. My sum range starts at row 2 and same column as the formula is in (R2C) and extends to one row above and same column as the current formula cell (R[-1]C). Does that help?? You can see all the codes for the first parameter at: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/subtotal.php